# Objective C, A Question about iterating through protocol variables

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Let's say I have defined my own protocol and named it as NeighborNodeListener. 
And I have NSMutableArray that holding objects that implements the protocol. 
Now, I want to iterate through the NSMutalble array and call one of the methods that defined in the protocol for all the objects in the array.

```
 for(id <NeighborNodeListener> object in listeners){
      [object firstMethod];//first method is defined in the protocol 
 }
```

I was thinking about doing something likt this but it didn't work.
The code I want to do in Objective C would look like this in Java

```
 List<NeighborNodeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<NeighborNodeListener>();
 Iterator<NeighborNodeListener> iter = listeners.iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
      iter.next().firstMethod();
 }
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "didn't work". That's not incredibly specific, and judging from your code, nothing seems to be wrong with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C is a little less strict than Java in terms of typing, so you'll need to check at runtime.

Note that the two code blocks below do the same thing -- except that the first checks `object` for complete conformance to the protocol, whereas the latter just checks for the method you'd like to call.

```
for (id object in listeners)
{
  if ([object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(myProtocol)])
  {
    [object firstMethod];//first method is defined in the protocol
  }
  else
  {
    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"objects in the listeners array must confirm to myProtocol"];
  }
}
```

Or,

```
for (id object in listeners)
{
  if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(firstMethod)])
  {
    [object firstMethod];//first method is defined in the protocol
  }
  else
  {
    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"objects in the listeners array must confirm to myProtocol"];
  }
}
```